# Problema con efecto de botón en CSS

Tags: html, css

estoy creando un botón transition con css pero la letra se sale de este. El efecto de diseño del botón es como se muestra en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora este el código que estoy usando:

```css
#btnCrear{
    padding: 1px 15px 3px 2px;
    border-radius:50px;    
    width: 32px;    
   
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -o-transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    
    -webkit-transition: width 1s, background 1s;
    -moz-transition: width 1s, background 1s;
    -o-transition: width 1s, background 1s;
    transition: width 1s, background 1s;
   
   }

#btnCrear:hover {
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button style="float:right;" id="btnCrear">
problema
</button>
```

Por ello solicito su ayuda compañeros, ya que no he encontrado ninguna solución en la red.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solo tienes que agregarle `overflow: hidden` a tu botón, de esta forma:

```css
#btnCrear {
  padding: 1px 15px 3px 2px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 32px;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
  -o-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s, background 1s;
  -moz-transition: width 1s, background 1s;
  -o-transition: width 1s, background 1s;
  transition: width 1s, background 1s;
  overflow: hidden; /* Ocultamos todo lo que se salga del ancho deseado */
}

#btnCrear:hover {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button style="float:right;" id="btnCrear">
problema
</button>
```

Documentación sobre [`oveflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabia sobre la función Overflow, me ayudaste para mi efecto de botón.

Answer (score 0):

Para que el texto se mueva correctamente con la animación y estilizarlo más, lo mejor es alinearlo a la izquierda con la propiedad text-indent, el padding lo limpias completamente, colocas el ancho y alto inicial según en tamaño de la imagen que vas a colocar y ocultas el overflow:

```
#btnCrear{
    padding: 0; /* quitas los valores iniciales */
    text-indent: 30px; /* varía segun la imagen inicial del boton */
    border-radius: 50px;
    /* ancho y alto inicial */
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    text-align: left; /* a la izquierda */
    overflow: hidden; /* que no se vea el texto sobresaliente */

    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -o-transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-timing-function: linear;

    -webkit-transition: width 1s, background 1s;
    -moz-transition: width 1s, background 1s;
    -o-transition: width 1s, background 1s;
    transition: width 1s, background 1s;
}
```